# AZURE. Redirect to a path in Application Gateway

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-application-gateway

So I have a angular SPA application deployed in a blob storage and an appService container backend. Now I've exposed the application in AppGateway with this rules:

- Type: Path-based
- Listener: httpsListener
- Default Backend pool: blobStoragePool
- Paths:
- name: api; Paths: /api/*; BackendPool: appServicePool

Everything runs fine but if I access directly https://myapp.cloudapp.azure.com/login I get a 404 because the .htaccess is not being proccessed (*because it's just a plain blob web storage*), so the next step was to try to make another redirection like:

- *name: root; Paths: /.+; BackendPool: blobPool*

There is a [suggestion](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/217313-networking/suggestions/38493931-allow-regex-search-patterns-for-url-path-patterns) for this in triage to use reg-exp so this approach is a no-go.

**TL/DR: How can I redirect to / when path is not /api/* ?**

---

**EDIT1:**

[image: Path-based rule]

Comment: Can you provide your sample code or screenshots? Could you set a path based rule for /* + BackendPool: blobPool?

Comment: I've attached a screenshot of the Path-based rule on the appGateway

Answer (score 0):

One workaround is to provide index.html as error document path in the storage account static website. This is not ideal, the good way would be to redirect to do a 301 to index.html

I'll leave this here just in case someone comes across the same issue.

Comment: Your page will send a 404 error to scrawler but user can see it